# System.out.print of string without 'ln'

Tags: java, arrays, string, system.out

I have a byte array which looks like this:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 122, 98, 117, 54, 46, 0, 0, 115, 122, 42, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 116, 121, 116, 117, 108, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 107, 111, 98, 105, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 122, 42, 109, 111, 119, 40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 107, 111, 98, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 98, 111, 40]
```

I wanted to print it as a string, so I wrote the following code:

```java
System.out.println(new String(byteArray));
```

but there is no output. Next, I tried the following code:

```java
for (byte b : byteArray) {
    System.out.print((char) b);
}
```

but again there is no output. But when I tried the following code:

```java
for (byte b : byteArray) {
    System.out.println((char) b);
}
```

I was able to see the values.

My question is, why can't I create a string or why did the first printing of values from `byteArray` fail?

Comment: Nope, all worked just fine for me...

Comment: well, they are all giving the same result in my computer..
the only difference is the `ln` gives me many lines..

Comment: Do you have any calls to `System.setOut()` anywhere?

Comment: Does adding `System.out.flush()` help at all?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(byteArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 122, 98, 117, 54, 46, 0, 0, 115, 122, 42, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 116, 121, 116, 117, 108, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 107, 111, 98, 105, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 122, 42, 109, 111, 119, 40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 107, 111, 98, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 98, 111, 40};
System.out.println(new String(bytes));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your byte array is mostly non printable characters, with a few random letters mixed in. But all you need is:

```java
String myString = new String(byteArray);
```

which will give you a valid string.

Try out the following code, as maybe it will better illustrate the issue your having:

```java
for (char c : new String(byteArray).toCharArray()) {
    System.out.printf("Character: %s Hex: %02x \n", c, (int) c);
}
```

Comment: I want to convert my byte array into characters. But after using what you suggested, nothing appears

Comment: Edited my answer after your clarification, hopefully that solves it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`String(byte[],Charset)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte%5B%5D,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)) constructor and specify a [`Charset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) to be used to decode this array of `bytes`:

```java
System.out.println(new String(byteArray, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

In most cases, [`StandardCharsets.UTF_8`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html#UTF_8) is a default charset.