# Java Eclipse - string wrapping for System.out.println()

Tags: java, eclipse, string, arrays, system.out

I asked for help with [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22494948/system-out-print-of-string-without-ln) in which, when I want to convert bytes from table

```
`[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 122, 98, 117, 54, 46, 0, 0, 115, 122, 42, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 116, 121, 116, 117, 108, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 107, 111, 98, 105, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 122, 42, 109, 111, 119, 40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 107, 111, 98, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 98, 111, 40]`
```

into characters and print this characters. When I make:

```
    for(byte b: byteArray){
        System.out.print((char) b);
    }
```

I don't have anything on my console. Even the scroll bars are the same length.
But when I make:

```
for(byte b: byteArray){
 System.out.println((char) b);
}
```

it works good. 
I think this is eclipse problem, not with the code. I unchecked the limit console output, but it didn't helped.

Comment: You are aware that certain encodings are not one-byte-per-char, right? What encoding do you use, and why don't you use the `String(byte[], Charset)` constructor?

Comment: How about `System.out.print(new String(byteArray));`

Comment: @MohammadAdil I was trying also that. But still nothing appears

Comment: @Rop i tried System.out.print((char) b); and in my eclipse console it works fine. There must be something wrong with ur eclipse. And Mohammeds solution worked too.

Comment: @kai I guessed, but I don't know what my be wrong with my eclipse

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to exclude the non-printable chars, like 0

```
for(byte b: byteArray){
    System.out.print(b >= 32 ? (char) b : "");
}
```

You can replace the blank String for whatever you need as "?" or "[ascii_code]"...

I've tested using your data and In my Eclipse (OSX) appears in both cases, my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] bytes =
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 122, 98, 117, 54, 46, 0, 0, 115, 122, 42, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 116, 121, 116, 117, 108, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 107, 111, 98, 105, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 122, 42, 109, 111, 119, 40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 107, 111, 98, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 98, 111, 40 };
    System.out.println("Init...");
    for (byte b : bytes) {
        System.out.print((char) b);
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    for (byte b : bytes) {
        System.out.print(b >= 32 ? (char) b : "?");
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("End");
}
```

The output for that is:

```
Init...
zbu6.sz*tytul kobiz*mow(kobbo(

????????zbu6.??sz*???????????tytul?????????????????????? kobi????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????z*mow(??????kob?????bo(
End
```

Answer (score 0):

char is of 2 byte , if byte number is out of range -128 to 127 ,

Answer (score 0):

try to do

```
for(byte b: byteArray){
    System.out.print((char) b);
}
System.out.println();
```

The method `print` may be buffered and not shown while you don't print `\n`

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in your environment for sure.

my eclipse console output this with your first loop:

[image]

funny thing, i can't copy/paste this output. i think it's \0 bytes fault.

Answer (score 0):

The console is reacting badly to the [null character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) `\u0000` which is often used as [a string terminator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string).

Eclipse uses SWT which often uses native controls where possible so it may be that there's a defect in the underlying UI toolkit or how SWT uses it.

This has been reported before - [Bug 362957 - The Console does not display '\u0000' correctly](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=362957) - so you might want to add your input to the bug report and vote on it.

I would include:

- Operating system/version
- Eclipse and SWT build versions (look in the plugins directory)

  - any changes if any you've made to the stylesheets (e.g. e4_default_gtk.css)
- The platform UI toolkit version if applicable (e.g. GTK)
- The font - [see Preferences](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-fonts.htm?cp=0_4_1_13)
- Java version (probably irrelevant)