# How to convert csv String to bytestream

Tags: java, string, csv, io

I have some strings that represent lines in a CSV:

```java
String headers = "Date,Color,Model,Price";

String line1 = "12-03-2012,Red,Toyota,13500";
```

I want to return a bytestream that would correspond to the corresponding csv file. I've seen how to convert csv files to strings (using `InputStream` and `BufferedReader`), but not the reverse operation. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String.getBytes(Charset)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes(java.nio.charset.Charset)) method for this purpose:

```java
String str = "Lorem ipsum";

byte[] arr = str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
// [76, 111, 114, 101, 109, 32, 105, 112, 115, 117, 109]
```

---

<sup>See also:

• [System.out.print of string without 'ln'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65371994/14838237)

• [Splitting a string containing multi-byte characters into an array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65518371/14838237)</sup>